# File permissions using cacls, icals for USB drive in FAT format?

Tags: windows, usb, dos, ntfs, fat32

I'm creating a desktop application. This application runs only if its in **USB drive**. In my application i used MS DOS commands like `cacls`, `icals` for giving access permission. My problem is, these commands will work only if **the USB drive is in NTFS** format only, when I change the file format to FAT the above commands doesn't work. Is there any possible to run this commands when the USB drive in FAT. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAT filesystem doesn't have a rich set of file permissions like NTFS does, so depending on what you need to do with these permissions, you might be out of luck.

Comment: in FAT filesystem we can't use ACL?